# Elixir - Composing string inside of a "use" statement does not work

Tags: string, import, elixir, interceptor

I am currently attempting to `use` the [Interceptor](https://hexdocs.pm/interceptor/Interceptor.html) library inside my own module. To do this I need to provide a config parameter. This parameter consists of a map in which the keys are strings representing which functions of which modules have to be intercepted and the values consist of a list with information on how the interception should take place. I am specifically searching for help with the keys.

As I explained, my keys are strings representing the function to be intercepted. They are formated as such: `moduleName.functionName/arity`. When just hardcoding this string, everything works. However, I would like to be able to dynamically form this string. More specifically, I would like to dynamically fill in the module name. The reason for this is that I would like to inject this piece of code at a later stage using macro's and then I will not know the module beforehand. The functionname and arity I will be able to know beforehand and hardcode.

My code currently looks as follows:

```
use Interceptor, config: %{
    String.slice(to_string(__MODULE__), 7..-1) <> ".someFunction/2" => [
      before: "SpecialInterceptor.intercept_before/1",
      after: "SpecialInterceptor.intercept_after/2"
    ]
  }
```

Note, the reason why I slice the string is because `__MODULE__` prefixes the name of the module with "Elixir". For example, `Elixir.ModuleName`. As such, I need to slice that part of.

When I use this code snippet in my module to setup the Interceptor, it doesn't work. The code runs without errors, but nothing gets intercepted. When I replace the `String.slice(to_string(__MODULE__), 7..-1) <> ".someFunction/2"` with `"SomeModule" <> ".someFunction/2"` it does work.

I'm hoping someone could shine some light on what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

In the first place, one does not do `String.slice/2` to get the module name as a string, but rather does [`Kernel.inspect/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#inspect/2).

```elixir
inspect(String)
#⇒ "String"
```

Then, one does not construct the function capture manually, but rather uses [`Function.capture/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Function.html#capture/3), because manual string concatenation needs thorough testing for [absolutely valid] module names like `:"I ❤ NY"`.

```elixir
Function.capture(String, :length, 1) |> inspect  
#⇒"&String.length/1"
```

And, the last but not the least, `use/2` is a syntactic sugar for [`__using__/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#use/2), which is a macro, and remote calls in their arguments are passed to its implementation as AST. But macros can expand module arguments from the context, which would help in such a case.

That said, the proper code would be somewhat alongside the following.

```elixir
defmodule Intercepted do
  @config %{
    __MODULE__
    |> Function.capture(:some_function, 2)
    |> inspect()
    |> String.trim_leading("&") => […]
  }
  use Interceptor, config: @config

  …
end
```

---

<del>*Sidenote:* I bet you don’t actually need to stringify capture.</del> — I see, this is the 3<sup>rd</sup>-party requirement.

Comment: Hi! When reading [this documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/interceptor/Interceptor.html#module-intercept-configuration-on-the-intercepted-module) I seem to need a String. However, when playing around with your solution I seem to end up with something else, a closure of some sort? Additionally, I get the following error when using the `@` notation you used: `(ArgumentError) cannot invoke @/1 outside module`. This is weird as I do use it inside of my module. I'm rather new to Elixir, so it might also be me missunderstanding things.

Comment: Ouch, indeed, I missed this is all to fulfill requirements of the 3rd party library. I have amended the answer, sorry for the mess.